# Not show marker.message and marker.code in hover message

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco Editor to make my own IDE. I use `provideHover` over certain kinds of code.

I realize that the hover window shows several texts. One kind of texts come from [contents](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.hover.html#contents); another kind of texts consist of `marker.message` and `marker.code` (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imarker.html).

Does anyone know if it is possible to not show these the texts consisting of `marker.message` and `marker.code`?

[image]

PS: code of `provideHover`:

```
public async provideHover(model: monaco.editor.ITextModel, position: monaco.Position, token: CancellationToken): Promise<monaco.languages.Hover | undefined> {
    let marker = monaco.editor.getModelMarkers({}).find(marker => { // https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#getmodelmarkers
        let markerStart = new monaco.Position(marker.startLineNumber, marker.startColumn);
        let markerEnd = new monaco.Position(marker.endLineNumber, marker.endColumn);
        if (markerStart.isBeforeOrEqual(position) && position.isBeforeOrEqual(markerEnd)) return marker;
        return null;
    });

    if (marker != null) {
        if (marker.code == "113") {
            return {
                contents: [{
                    value: "contents[0].value ",
                    isTrusted: false
                }
                , {
                    value: "contents[1].value",
                    isTrusted: false
                }
            ]
            };                
        }
    }
    return undefined
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `provideHover`?

Comment: Please see my PS.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar behavior with Monaco Editor, the reason was that I by mistake **registered the hoverProvider multiple times** (not directly, but there was a wired condition that led to multiple instantiations).

Hope that helps!